# No cache event samples for ARM beagleboard running Android

Tags: android, arm, beagleboard, cpu-cache, oprofile

I am trying to collect some performance statistics on Beagleboard Rev C4, and Beagleboard xM.

Oprofile runs perfectly when I set the profiling event to CPU_CYCLE, however on both boards, when I try to profile any cache related events, I get an empty samples folder and no result.

I did not get any error (not even in the kernel messages) when I run oprofile with

```
opcontrol --event=L1_DATA_MISS:10000
```

But profiling seem to have failed.  It's the same story for all other cache related events.  Am I doing something wrong, or are these PMUs unavailable on Beagleboards?

Comment: I think the best bet would be to ask Eranian;